# Sending a parameter to JS function using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

I am attempting to run two different functions which do two separate things. Both need to run when a div is clicked on. The div is generated in the innerHTML function of JavaScript.

This is the method that runs second. It takes one parameter and then generates a div on the page.

```
//Display larger image:
function furtherDetails(mainImage){
    var moreInfo = document.getElementById('divpropertyInfo');
    moreInfo.innerHTML = '<div id="propInfoDisplay">' +
                            '<img id="image" src="'+mainImage+'" alt="Main Image" />' +
                        '</div>';
}
```

This is the code that runs that function:

```
//Create the property div:
function createPropertyDiv(mainImage, bedrooms, bathrooms, parkings, price, address, latitude, longitude){

    var propertyDiv = document.getElementById('divsearchResults');
    propertyDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="divResults" onclick="showMap('+latitude+','+longitude+');furtherDetails('+mainImage+');">' +
                                '<img id="mainImage" src="' + mainImage +'" alt="Main Image" />' +
                                '<p id="numBedrooms">'+ bedrooms +'</p>' +
                                '<img id="bedroomsImage" src="/images/bedrooms.png" />' +
                                '<p id="numBathrooms">'+ bathrooms +'</p>' +
                                '<img id="bathroomsImage" src="/images/bathrooms.png" />' +
                                '<p id="numParking">'+ parkings +'</p>' +
                                '<img id="parkingImage" src="/images/carspots.png" />' +
                                '<p id="Price">'+ price +'</p>' +
                                '<p id="addressHeading">Address: </p>' +
                                '<p id="Address">' + address + '</p>' +
                            '</div>';
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: when you get this error?  the time when you click on that ?

Comment: @Christopher I don't think the error is from these two functions can you share a working snippet showing the error, if possible a JSFiddle?

Comment: check Your functions for pair of `(` & `)`

Comment: @Farsay yes only when i click on it.

Comment: @Naren The error is in one of these functions. The furtherDetails() function runs when I do not parse any parameters to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variables inside `onclick` need to be surrounded by `'` or `"`, otherwise they will be evaluated before the click, leading to your syntax error.

```
onclick="showMap(\''+latitude+'\',\''+longitude+'\');furtherDetails(\''+mainImage+'\')
```

Simple example

```js
let el = document.getElementById('foo');
let f = "bar";

function bar(c) {
  console.log(c);
}

el.innerHTML += '<div onclick="bar(\'' + f + '\')">Baz</div>'; // logs the value of f
el.innerHTML += '<div onclick="bar(' + f + ')">Boo</div>'; // logs the function bar
```

```html
<div id="foo">
Foo
</div>
```

That being said, don't use inline javascript. Use an eventListener instead. Then you can just pass whatever you want to the function without having to worry about escaping, and you can call as many functions as you wish from the listener.

```js
function foo(bar) {
  console.log(bar);
}
let bar = 'bar';

let el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'resultDiv';
el.appendChild(document.createTextNode('child'));

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  foo(bar);
}, false);

document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(el);
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is here

According to your code html will be something like this -

```
<div id="divResults" onclick="showMap(1,3);furtherDetails(images/123.jpg);">
```

**you have to escape string by using \" and your html should be like this -**

```
<div id="divResults" onclick="showMap(1,3); furtherDetails('images/123.jpg');">
```